# Rendering an infinite tree with custom template

Tags: angular, angular-template

This maybe a common/simple problem but I'm new to angular. So, I am caught up in this.

I am trying to build an application that requires rendering a list from a data structure that is infinitely nested (By infinitely, I mean unknown number of nesting). I have been able to do a recursion in html code after following [this article](https://blog.imaginea.com/render-an-infinite-tree-in-angular-2/).

So, the basic idea is to provide a data and a recursionKey and to put the component tag in the component template itself. (Basic Recursion)

But I want to create a generic component in which the cell layout can be defined at the application/implementation level.

What I've built till now -

**novo-rec-list-view.component**

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource.length">
<div *ngFor="let item of dataSource">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"></ng-template>
    <novo-rec-list-view [recursionKey]="recursionKey" [dataSource]="item[recursionKey]"></novo-rec-list-view>
</div>
```

and I am using this component as -

```
<novo-rec-list-view 
        id="change-log-list" 
        [recursionKey]="recursionKey"
        [dataSource]="treeNodeList">
    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="$implicit" let-i="index">
      <change-log-cell [item]="item">
      </change-log-cell>
    </ng-template>
</novo-rec-list-view>
```

where **change-log-cell** contains the layout of the cell.

Can this be achieved in angular4? Can someone provide me some pointers on how to do this?

Minimal working app based on the code above - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snub7u?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

PS - Not able to achieve recursion and therefore inner elements are not being displayed.

Comment: What you're looking to do can be achieved, but to provide you with an answer can you give me a couple more details?

1. When you say layout, what do you mean by that? Are you talking about styling such as CSS?
2. Are there any other dynamic things about this generic component you're looking to be able to do outside of just the layout?

Comment: hey @bitW0lf. Thanks for commenting. By layout, 1. I mean the html layout (template) of the cell. Actually, to be precise, **change-log-cell** is itself a component.
2. No, I haven't thought of any. I am starting with this basic generic component only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer above, I am going to throw 2 ideas out there for you. Not sure if either will work for what you want. If not, I could brainstorm and edit this answer.

If you need a base generic component and need to modify styles around it based upon certain details in the item input you could use `ngClass` or any of the other ways to dynamically alter style binding. I'm linking you to a really helpful article below:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

The other thing that you could do, depending on how complex the changes to the html would be is create multiple templates within `change-log-cell` (which I am not sure you want to do) and then use an `ngSwitch` keying off of whatever you need to in the item input to determine which switch case you want to render within the html. Pointing you to the official Angular docs on how that works:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Comment: Thanks for providing such a useful information. I am unable to achieve recursion and therefore inner elements are not being displayed. I have created a minimal app for showcasing what I've done. Can you please have a look and suggest me changes for achieving the same. 
App link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snub7u?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts
PS - I have edited my question to include this too.

Comment: Thanks for the stackblitz, to get the sub-items to show, your `change-log-cell` component needs to call itself so that it ensures it will call as far down the tree as your object has items to go. If I put this inside of `cell.template.html` I get the sub-items: `<change-log-cell *ngFor="let i of item.children" [item]="i">
</change-log-cell>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I think with this, I might be able to abstract out my list component a little better allowing recursion at the implementation level. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help, if you wouldn’t mind marking this answer as correct so that I get the points I’d greatly appreciate it! Have a good one.